# Oxygine c++ Event Listener error

Tags: c++, box2d, game-engine

I use Oxygine framework and whem i try to add an event listener to a sprite it gives me this error when using CLOSURE

This is my class

```
#include "MainActor.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "Hero.h"
#include "res.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace oxygine;

spHero hero;

MainActor::MainActor(): _world(0) { 
   setSize(getStage()->getSize());
   spMap map = new Map("map.xml", "Sprites.png");
   addChild(map);
   _world = new b2World(b2Vec2(0, 10));   

   hero = new Hero(100, 10, 0, 100, 
   res::resources.getResAnim("hero_idle_up"), _world, getSize() / 2,
   0.6);    
   addChild(hero);
   map->addEventListener(TouchEvent::CLICK, CLOSURE(this, 
   &MainActor::Move)); 
}

void MainActor::Move(Event* ev) {   
     TouchEvent* tev = safeCast<TouchEvent*>(ev);   
     hero->addTween(TweenPosition(tev->localPosition), 1000);   
}
```

and at this line it gives the folowing error

```
map->addEventListener(TouchEvent::CLICK, CLOSURE(this, &MainActor::Move));
```

Error : no instance of overloaded function "detail::CreateClosure" matches the argument list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an imprudence because one of the methods do not corresponds with one from the header file. It is solved now